# The result of $_GET is getting corrupted

Tags: php, url

I am working on a password system, where an email is sent and they have to click on a link to go to a page where the password is reset.

There is some information in the link which is encrypted, and then supposedly de-encrypted on the other side.
Here is an example
http://www.somewebpage.com?p=8e428904890e31a93c563e1f18c11ff6&c=U2FsdGVkX1+LdNFKzCZxRAGPYYA9MGzAhAUh/wLJ3T4=

Now I use $_GET['c'] to get the encrypted data.
Then I decrypt it using my Decrypt code.

Now here is the problem
If I do this it works

```
Decrypt($key,"U2FsdGVkX1+LdNFKzCZxRAGPYYA9MGzAhAUh/wLJ3T4=");
```

and it gives me back my original text.

but if I do this. It doesn't work

```
Decrypt($key,$_GET['c']);
```

It just gives me mangled characters.

The question is why doesn't my encrypt routine work when I user $_GET['c'] and works if I put the string in directly.

Is the web url adding hidden characters or something?
If so can I strip anything added.

Comment: use `urldecode` before decrypting

Comment: What is `echo $_GET['c']`?

Comment: You need to properly encode values that you put into a URL. `=` obviously has a special meaning inside a query string. `&c=…=` should quite obviously raise some eyebrows. Where are you generating that URL…?

Comment: $_GET['c'] will not have the trailing `=`, so you're Decrypting a different string to what you think you're Decrypting

Comment: @RamRaider No, `$_GET` values are already url-decoded. That's also not the issue.

Comment: @iblamefish And `+` (can) mean(s) "space"…

Comment: Print out `$_GET['c']` to see what you actually got.

Comment: what does var_dump($_GET['c']); say?

Comment: Use `%2B` in the query string value instead of `+` and `%3D` instead of `=`

Comment: echo $_GET['c'] is giving me the correct string, but I suspect something invisible is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encrypt data contain some character that will not pass through browser correctly.

When you are generate the key try to use function urlencode()

```
echo '<a href="mycgi?foo=', urlencode($encryptdata), '">';
```

Comment: I will look into this now, and let you know

Comment: This worked. I thank you. Been doing php for a few years, but not needed to send an encode url before.

Comment: BTW, normally we don't send encrypt data for this problems. Why due to we not sure if the size of the data are too large for URL or not. (one ! character can produce 3 character ! = %21 )
We send just a random token, store in database, along with username and if those person provide the correct token that match data you have. That mean it's a correct person.

Comment: I agree. I am only sending 2 pieces of information. One of them is my token. The only reason it looks long is because of the encryption adds padding. I know encrypting my token may be going to far, but you can never have enough encryption LOL